# GWT FileUpload with Progress Listener

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt, servlets

I want to observe the upload percentage of a file upload from GWT.

In JavaScript you can use a XMLHttpRequest and add an event listener like this:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}
```

(The above code is from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).)

This is also done very easily in jQuery as:

```
 var $request = $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
        xhrNativeObject = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        //Upload progress
        xhrNativeObject.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) { ... }
      }
 });
```

I want to do the same with GWT. I could use a [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) to send a request, but this is only a high level wrapper around the XMLHttpRequest JavaScriot object. Another possibility would be to use the GWT [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/xhr/client/XMLHttpRequest.html) class which is a JSNI wrapper of the JavaScript XMLHttpRequest.

My problem:

**How can I add a progress listener to the XMLHttpRequest or the RequestBuilder?**

Answer (score 1):

I used before gwt-upload library.

You dont need to rediscover America.

Thanks for moxie group

[gwt-upload-project page](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/)

Comment: Can you provide an example how I can use this with a non GWT backend and without the ui provided by gwt-upload?

Answer (score 0):

```
//upload spring service conroller
@RequestBody public void uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ){
  //what ever you want
}
```

XML Configuration

```
<bean id=multipartResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Comment: @ I use Grails as backend. I did not get how you handle the GWT part for the upload progress?

Comment: on my first answer , gwt-upload project has also progressbar. i dont handle it. when file uploading it shows a progress. if you implement your own upload component i dont know how it is works.

Comment: sorry but this does not help me

Answer (score 0):

[GWT Elemental](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html) contains all you need already AFAICT.

Comment: I did not find when GWT Element has a progress listener.

Comment: I'm talking about the `elemental.xml.XMLHttpRequest`, `elemental.xml.XMLHttpRequestUpload`, `elemental.events.XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent`, and `elemental.html.FormData` classes from the `gwt-elemental` JAR (with `<inherits name="elemental.Elemental" />`)

Comment: Could you please post a short example I could not figure out how it works.